# Singletons factory using generics and reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, singleton, factory

OrderDBManager, UserDBManager, ProductDBManager extend DBManager.
I'm trying to create a singletons DBManager Factory
to get instances of different DBManager type classes.

But I have a problem using generics to return an instance of exact DBManager type class user wants. Right now it only works for DBManager itself.
I would appreciate your help!

```
public class DBManagerFactory {

     private static final Map<String, DBManager> instances = new HashMap<>();

     private static final String DB_MANAGER_PACKAGE_NAME = "ua.Test.db.";

     public static DBManager getInstance(Class<? extends DBManager> dbManagerClass) {
            String dbManagerClassName = dbManagerClass.getSimpleName();
            DBManager dbManager = instances.get(dbManagerClassName);

            if(dbManager == null){
                Class clazz = Class.forName(DB_MANAGER_PACKAGE_NAME + dbManagerClassName);
                dbManager = (DBManager)clazz.newInstance();
                instances.put(dbManagerClassName, dbManager);    
            }
            return dbManager;                                             
     }}
```

Comment: What’s the point of this `Class.forName(DB_MANAGER_PACKAGE_NAME + dbManagerClassName)`? The caller already provided a `Class` object to you.

Answer (score 1):

> But I have a problem using generics to return an instance of exact
>   DBManager type class user wants.

To return a specific class in the method, you should specify a scoped method parameterized type that allows the client of the class to specify which type the method should return.

You could declare the method in this way :

```
public static <T extends DBManager> T getInstance(Class<T> dbManagerClass)  {
```

To avoid unsafe casts, you could cast the `DBManager` instance retrieved from the `Map<String, DBManager>` to a `T extends DBManager` type by using the `Class#cast(Object )` method that performs for you the type check before casting the `DBManager` instance :

```
T dbManager = dbManagerClass.cast(instances.get(dbManagerClassName));
```

At last, the way to retrieve the class :

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(DB_MANAGER_PACKAGE_NAME + dbManagerClassName);
```

is not required as you have already the class as parameter of the method.
Just directly use it.

Here is sample code that implements this solution :

```
public class DBManagerFactory {

    private static final Map<String, DBManager> instances = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T extends DBManager> T getInstance(Class<T> dbManagerClass)  {

      final String dbManagerClassName = dbManagerClass.getSimpleName();

      T dbManager = dbManagerClass.cast(instances.get(dbManagerClassName));

      if (dbManager == null) {
        try {
          dbManager =  dbManagerClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace(); // or better log it
          throw new RuntimeException("faillure during reflection instantiation for class " + dbManagerClass.getName(), e);
        }
        instances.put(dbManagerClassName, dbManager);
      }

      return dbManager;
    }   

}
```

With these modifications, the client classes could invoke the method in this way :

```
DBManager instance = DBManagerFactory.getInstance(DBManager.class);
DBManagerChild child = DBManagerFactory.getInstance(DBManagerChild.class);
```

Comment: You should not use an unchecked cast like `(T) …`. Instead, use `dbManagerClass.cast( … )`. As a side note, if the OP used `dbManagerClass.newInstance()`, the returned reference had already the type `T`. The OP’s entire dealing with names looks wrong anyway…

Comment: @Holger  You are totally right. I would avoid to change the way the OP uses to retrieve the class : `Class clazz = Class.forName(DB_MANAGER_PACKAGE_NAME + dbManagerClassName);`  As you noticed, it is not correctly used.  I just modified to give a better and more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get explicit return type, then you could use [generic factory method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html), as follows:

```
class Base {}

class A extends Base {}

class B extends Base {}

class InitializationFailedException extends RuntimeException {
    public InitializationFailedException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}

class Factory {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Factory.class);

    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Class<? extends Base>, Base> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static  <T extends Base> T getInstance(Class<T> tClass) {
        if (tClass == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return (T) instances.computeIfAbsent(tClass, (tClass1) -> {
            try {
                return tClass1.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                log.error("Unable to create singleton value for " + tClass1.getCanonicalName(), e);
                throw new InitializationFailedException(e);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

With this approach you can get you sub type references created:

```
A aInstance = Factory.getInstance(A.class);
B bInstance = Factory.getInstance(B.class);
```

for your problem method signature can look like:

```
public static <T extends DBManager> T getInstance(Class<T> dbManagerClass);
```

instances Map should look like:

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends DBManager>, DBManager> instances = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Ok. Then how should map declaration look?

Comment: The logic to get an explicit return type is ok, only be careful with HashMap, which is not synchronized. In a production environment, this code should be modified to avoid breaking the hashMap.

Comment: @LuigiRubino the question is about generics, not about thread safety or any other important but **separate** topic

Comment: `throws Exception`? There's an antipattern.

Comment: @LewBloch You are correct. However, I personally don't like when answers contain a lot of "production ready" unnecessary code, which can bring more confusion rather than value. Anyway, modified the answer.